# Does the switching of a synchronization context mean that the work will run on the thread that owns the synchronization context?

Tags: .net, multithreading, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, synchronizationcontext

Whether you run a *task* (and *not `Task`*) like so:

```
public async void button1_click(...)
{
    await Task.Run(...);
}
```

or using on the of old methods where you call `InvokeRequired` to check if there is a need to invoke the current operation on another synchronization context, and then call the `Control.Invoke` (in the case of WinForms, for example), the operation is performed using the captured synchronization context, if there is one.

However, which of the two things does this mean?

If you request a task to be run on a thread pool thread using any of the methods, whether old or new, does it mean that:

1. When the thread gets off the ground, the switching of synchronization context means that it will wait for the thread that owns the synchronization context to execute the piece of code? In the case of UI owned sync context, does it mean that the thread pool thread will post back the action to the message queue of the UI thread and yield?

   OR
2. Or does it mean that the thread pool thread will execute the action but there will simply be a switch of a reference variable (`System.Threading.ExecutionContext.SynchronizationContext`) that holds the synchronization context, and as such, the synchronization context is only a co-operative discipline that threads agree to adhere to? The work will still be done by the thread pool thread?

   Of course, by co-operative discipline*, I do not mean that everything will work alright even if miscreant thread decided not to switch the synchronization context where it was required. My implication is that the thread not owning the synchronization context initially can still run if the synchronizataion context reference is changed to the right one.

From reading the source code of [`AsyncMethodBuilder<TResult>.Start`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs,5916df9e324fc0a1), [`System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,2823) and [`System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs,de9ca2ef250c4a00) method, it seems highly likely that the answer is #2, but I am not sure.

**UPDATE**

Here is also why I assume #2 is more likely but I would love to be corrected.

If you just take a Windows Forms application and stick a button on it and run the code that is shown in the picture in the click event, you might see the call stack that looks like mine, as shown in the same picture.

[image]

I followed the source code of each method in the call stack. I observed that the context switch happens in the `System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal` method. It happens because the `System.Threading.Tasks.ExecuteWithThreadLocal` method passes the value `true` for the last parameter of its call to the `System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run` method. Please see [line 2823](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,2823).

However, thereafter, the call proceeds without any message posting to the UI thread's message queue and when it finally reaches the `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>.InnerInvoke` method, the method invokes the delegate.

If the answer is #1, if you could please show me where the message posting happens, I'll jump with joy and will have learnt something fascinating about the synchronization context today.

Does it happen in the `ExecutionContext.SetExecutionContext` method?

And if the answer is #2, and if you could confirm that, then, too, I will sing a song in celebration of my discovery.

> **Side Note**
>
> I made this program to test something different, though. I wanted to
>   see *where* the synchronization context is switched, if it is
>   required, both:
>
> 1. Before the `await` statement is reached; and
> 2. After the `await` statement, i.e on the *continuation callback*.
>
> And my findings have satisfactorily revealed to me the answers to both
>   the questions.
>
> For anyone curious, the switch is made in the `AsyncMethodBuilder`'s
>   `Start` method for any code that is *before* the `await` expression.
>
> For code that is after, there is more than one path. One of the paths
>   is depicted in this call stack that is shown in the picture above.

Comment: Your assumption is not correct, Control.Begin/Invoke() does **not** use a synchronization context.  It is the other way around, it is SynchronizationContext that uses Control.Begin/Invoke().  Specifically the WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext instance that gets installed automatically whenever you create a control or call Application.Run().  Your question stops making sense with that essential detail in place.

Comment: @HansPassant I am thinking about what you said.

Comment: @HansPassant I hold your correction in good stead. My knowledge of things is inexcusably limited. I am not sure how I can fix that immediately and rephrase my question. Gobbledygook as it might be, the gist of my question is: before a thread pool thread executes an action, if a sync context needs to be captured, does that force the thread pool thread to relinquish its time slice of the CPU and delegate that work back to the UI thread? Or does that mean the thread pool thread will execute the action prefacing it with a change in value of a reference variable that holds the sync context?

Comment: Nothing dramatic happens, it simply copies the value of SynchronizationContext.Currrent.

Comment: @HansPassant Many thanks. I suspected so. Would you like to put that down as an answer please?

Comment: My investigation on this matter is in progress and it looks like I might be nearing the end of it with some fruitful results.

Answer (score 4):

I have an [`async` intro blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) that explains how `await` works with `SynchronizationContext.Current`. Specifically, `await` uses the captured context to *resume* the `async` method.

So, this is not correct:

> the operation is performed using the captured synchronization context, if there is one.

If by "the operation", you mean the `...` in your code:

```
public async void button1_click(...)
{
  await Task.Run(...);
}
```

What would happen is that `Task.Run` will schedule `...` to a thread pool thread (`Task.Run` always uses the thread pool). The `await` then captures the current `SynchronizationContext` (in this case a UI context) and returns. When `...` completes, then the task returned by `Task.Run` will complete, and `button1_click` will resume on that context (the UI thread). It then reaches the end of the method and returns.

Within the `...`, `SynchronizationContext.Current` will be `null`. It is the task continuation set up by `await` that uses its captured `SynchronizationContext` to resume on the UI thread.

Comment: Thank you. I am not curious about what sync context an awaited operation or the continuation will run at. Both of those, I have learnt. By following the source code of the `System.Threading.Tasks.Task.SetContinuationForAwait` method (http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,f4ecbcb6398671fb) I was able to establish that the continuation ran on the right sync context. And with this question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/37635053/303685), I was able to learn what the value of the context will be inside of the thread pool thread delegate.

Comment: The gist of my question is: when a thread pool thread needs to run an action using the sync context of the UI thread, for instance, whether using TPL or otherwise, does that mean that the thread pool thread will post the delegate to the message queue of the UI thread so that the latter will execute it and will yield its slice of the CPU time? Or does it mean that the thread pool thread will execute the delegate but simply change a reference variable that holds the sync context before it does so?

Comment: BTW, I have read that intro article you have linked to and enjoyed it among other articles of yours. I intend to read your blog in its entirety.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2: For UI threads, it has to be a delegate posted to the message queue. It's not possible to have another thread temporarily become the UI thread.

Comment: Thank you. That nails it. Now I'm off to dig some code that I saw earlier that kind of sits ill with what you just said. Sorry, I am not trying to be difficult. I just want to set this right in my head once and for all so I can move on to other stuff.

Comment: I mean, it is entirely possible, and more likely so that I did not understand what I read. In fact, that's the only possibility. I just want to reconcile it with what you're saying.

Comment: I have updated the question with a picture and some commentary to describe what I saw.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2: I think you're making this way more complex than it is. The `...` is run on a thread pool thread; there's no SyncCtx or switching or anything. The entire call stack is executed on a thread pool thread.

Comment: I am afraid the answer is not very straightforward. I have been probing this issue since then and am nearing the end of my investigation. I anticipate I will know the truth about this soon and will be happy to share it.

Comment: I see why you think I would be over-complicating the issue. My question was never about *how would I switch sync context from within a task when I needed to?* That would be trivial. It is rather about *what happens internally when you switch a synchronization context?* I have now solved the case and the answer is a bit lengthy, but your initial answer was the correct one: the delegate *is posted back* to the UI thread. You changed your stance a bit after I posted a lengthy diatribe purporting my findings to the contrary of your initial assertion. :-)

Answer (score 1):

From reading some more code and thinking some more, it seems very likely that the answer is #2.

Here is the reasoning for this claim.

It would be terribly expensive to have the worker thread evacuate the CPU and cause a context switch just because it didn't own the synchronization context on which the operation needs to be executed.

The synchronization context is simply an object that includes the `HANDLE` to the window or resource that the thread wants to perform an operation on. If the thread that is presently executing does not have that synchronization context object, it would be much more frugal to copy a reference to the synchronization context that *does* own the resource handle and let the thread pool thread run using that context. This copy would have to be made before the thread takes its place on the CPU; in other words while it is still in the *ready queue* before it has begun operation.

It must also be noted that no new heap allocations are made during the copy as they would also be wasteful. Only a reference to the resource owning synchronization context is copied and set as the context of the current thread.

This theory of mine is supported by the following code snippets in the .NET framework source.

`AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<TResult>.Start` calls the `ExecutionContextReader` to copy the execution context that owns the resource and when it is done, it calls `Undo` on the `ExecutionContextSwitcher`, which reverses the previous operation.

```
[SecuritySafeCritical, DebuggerStepThrough, __DynamicallyInvokable]
public void Start<TStateMachine>(ref TStateMachine stateMachine) where TStateMachine: IAsyncStateMachine
{
    if (((TStateMachine) stateMachine) == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("stateMachine");
    }
    ExecutionContextSwitcher ecsw = new ExecutionContextSwitcher();
    RuntimeHelpers.PrepareConstrainedRegions();
    try
    {
        ExecutionContext.EstablishCopyOnWriteScope(ref ecsw);
        stateMachine.MoveNext();
    }
    finally
    {
        ecsw.Undo();
    }
}
```

The `System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal` method calls `ExecutionContext.Run` with the captured execution context asking it to preserve the captured execution context.

The `Run` method calls `ExecutionContext.RunInternal`, which does the same thing: makes a copy of the captured context and sets that as the execution context of the currently running thread. And when it is done, it calls the `ExecutionContextSwitcher.Undo` method to undo the previous copy operation and restore the thread's original execution context.

```
[SecurityCritical, HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
internal static void RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)
{
    if (!executionContext.IsPreAllocatedDefault)
    {
        executionContext.isNewCapture = false;
    }
    Thread currentThread = Thread.CurrentThread;
    ExecutionContextSwitcher ecsw = new ExecutionContextSwitcher();
    RuntimeHelpers.PrepareConstrainedRegions();
    try
    {
        Reader executionContextReader = currentThread.GetExecutionContextReader();
        if ((executionContextReader.IsNull || executionContextReader.IsDefaultFTContext(preserveSyncCtx)) && ((SecurityContext.CurrentlyInDefaultFTSecurityContext(executionContextReader) && executionContext.IsDefaultFTContext(preserveSyncCtx)) && executionContextReader.HasSameLocalValues(executionContext)))
        {
            EstablishCopyOnWriteScope(currentThread, true, ref ecsw);
        }
        else
        {
            if (executionContext.IsPreAllocatedDefault)
            {
                executionContext = new ExecutionContext();
            }
            ecsw = SetExecutionContext(executionContext, preserveSyncCtx);
        }
        callback(state);
    }
    finally
    {
        ecsw.Undo();
    }
}
```

Therefore, no work is posted back to the UI thread's message queue. Instead, the worker thread performs the work in the environment / synchronization context that owns the resource handle.

This means that the synchronization context is a co-operative discipline in that it is simply a protocol for copying heap objects that own operating system handles to the resources that a thread wants to use for its execution for the time it will be executing them.

Comment: I will be updating my answer with the findings of my further investigation on this matter. It appears that the proceedings are not as straightforward as my answer presently suggests.